# NS3 simulator will only installed on ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, mobile, simulator

i would like to work on NS3 simulator, will it only installed on ubuntu ?why?
as i am a windows users most of the people suggesting to use Virutalmachines in windows to install NS3 , i would like to know the reason.

NS3 simulator will only installed on ubuntu ?